# Azure Pipeline - Zip deployment

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have just begun in Azure DevOps.
I made the CI/CD pipeline for our dot net project. CI successfully done and generated the artifact, but in CD getting failed always, configured deployment type = zip;

I am completely new for Azure, so anyone look at this issue earlier and sorted out. Pls share your experience.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your array before red line says "There is not enough space on the disk". Please check your disk - probably storing or replacing the zip is not possible because of missing space.

Answer (score 0):

From the steps on the screenshot you shared, I do not see any step to archive the artifact files as a ZIP file.

Before the deployment, you need to use the [**Archive Files task**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/archive-files?view=azure-devops) to archive all the required artifact files as a ZIP file. Then execute the deployment with this ZIP file.

Comment: Hi @Saikumar, I have not heard from you for a long time. Just want to say hi and whether you have received my answer? Are the suggestions in my answer helpful for you?
As suggested, you need to use the Archive Files task to archive all the required artifact files as a ZIP file before the deploy task.

Comment: Sorry Bright Ran-MSFT. Finally got the solution like disk space issue. Finally we increased the space and getting succeed. Thanks for valuable suggestion.